# CiviCRM 5.01 Not Displaying Main Page (Page content is generated by CiviCRM)

Tags: wordpress, install

Folks,

I have a barebones WordPress 4.9.5 install with only the Updraft plugin enabled (default theme etc.).  I have configured the items listed in the CiviCRM (5.01) checklist, but am not able to get the main CRM page to load.  The following URL only displays the "Do not delete this page. Page content is generated by CiviCRM." message.

https://staging.secondchancenc.org/wp_2018/civicrm

I have confirmed that the CiviCRM resources are loadable from the path configure in CiviCRM:

https://staging.secondchancenc.org/wp_2018/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/gpl.txt

Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

that page you are referring to is used to generate CiviCRM content. As for "main page", are you referring to the CiviCRM Dashboard?  Your dashboard should be found at /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM